# Nextjs: Build optimization failed: found page without a React Component as default export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I run this command:

```
npm run build
```

And I get this error:

```
> Build optimization failed: found page without a React Component as default export in 
pages/library/store
```

And this is my `store.tsx`:

```
const store = new Map<string, any>();
export default store;
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: The default export from that file is a Map, which is indeed not a React component. Also it doesn't contain any JSX, so doesn't need to be a .tsx file.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks. so, I have to change this file to .js?

Comment: It does have _types_, so can't be a .js file.

Comment: @user3612383 Take a look at here, seems you can get some help in there :) 

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7094

Comment: I use this file for store my variable. So, how can I fix it?

Comment: @user3612383 I just updated the link, take another look please, cheers.

Comment: @Ali.Ghodrat this link could not help me!

Comment: @user3612383 no problem, just another link on GitHub, hope this one helps:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/9042

and this one:

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/9045/files#diff-3db9a9059285308854a7a947b817fc5d

Comment: Nextjs expects anything exported from the `/pages` directory to be a React component. You need to move this code outside of `/pages`.  This post discusses nextjs project structure: https://dev.to/vadorequest/a-2021-guide-about-structuring-your-next-js-project-in-a-flexible-and-efficient-way-472